# boost: command not found on mac OS 10.10

Tags: c++, boost, osx-yosemite, boost-python, caffe

I have been trying to install caffe Deep learning framework on my MAC OS 10.10, but there is a command which needs to be executed in this process.

```
boost snappy leveldb protobuf gflags glog szip lmdb homebrew/science/opencv
```

I installed boost library version 1.55.0 , still it gives this error.

```
-bash: boost: command not found
```

Also in this command: `make pycaffe`

I get this error:
`fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cuo] Error 1`

Where am I getting wrong?

Are environment variable needed to be set for this command to run.

Also,

What is meant by changing homebrew formula?

I am newbie in python. Before posting this on stack overflow, I tried a lot to figure our this error, but it is almost a week, I am not able to overcome. If possible, some step by step guide of caffe installation on mac 10.10 will be helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you using homebrew to install the packages?

Comment: @sbooth yes, I am using home-brew..

Comment: The installation instructions at http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html discuss how to edit the homebrew formulae.  Look for the line beginning with `def install`

Comment: Where should I copy that?

Comment: Ohh, I guess I need to edit all files.. There is actually no boost command. Editing every file with def install might solve the issue.. I am laughing at my mistakes. Thanx @sbooth

Comment: make pycaffe still gives the same error.. What should I do now @sbooth. Thanks in advance